# Load custom gifs from assets folder into recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, assets

I have created a subfolder named gifs in assets folder where I've added 5 gifs . I would like to display these gifs in a recyclerview but I have not been able to as the recyclerview is empty. I cant understand where am going wrong, please help me. Thanks in advance!

```java
public class GifAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < GifAdapter.GifViewHolder > {
    Context context;
    List<String> gifList;
    GifAdapterListener listener;

    public GifAdapter(Context context, GifAdapterListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gifList = loadGifs();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private List<String> loadGifs() {
        List<String> gifs = new ArrayList();
        gifs.add("a.gif");
        gifs.add("aa.gif");
        gifs.add("aaa.gif");
        gifs.add("aaaa.gif");
        gifs.add("aaaaa.gif");
        return gifs;
    }

    // more code

    // onBindViewHolder
    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GifViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("gifs");
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            holder.gifView.setBytes(bytes); // gifView is GifImageView using felipecsl.gifimageview library
            holder.gifView.startAnimation();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    // my fragment oncreate

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gif, container, false);

        recyclerGifs = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerGifs);
        recyclerGifs.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerGifs.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        gifAdapter = new GifAdapter(getContext(), this);
        recyclerGifs.setAdapter(gifAdapter);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to override `getItemCount` method for the adapter to know how many items are there in your list

Comment: Yes getItemCount is overriden..and I've returned gifsList.size..still not getting anything man!

Comment: okay let me edit the code to show the listeners and interfaces

Comment: Hey @VladyslavMatviienko kindly check the upvoted answer. Turns out as for my case, I only needed to modify it as follows  gifs.add("file:///android_asset/gifs/a.gif");   while adding the gifs into an arraylist since we are looking into the gifs subfolder in the assets folder. Tried it and it's working fiine. Thanks for your input too, really appreciate it!

Comment: `upvoted answer.` I suppose you mean *updated question*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make use of Glide and get gifs from assets like this:

```
private List<String> loadGifs() {
    List<String> gifs = new ArrayList();
    gifs.add("file:///android_asset/a.gif");
    gifs.add("file:///android_asset/aa.gif");
    gifs.add("file:///android_asset/aaa.gif");
    return gifs;
}
```

> Then load:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GifViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Glide.with(this).asGif().load(gifs(position)).into(imageView);
 }
```

> Simple example to load GIF:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(imageView);
```

Comment: thanks for your swift response. I've tried it but still I don't get any gif  item on the recyclerview :(

Comment: Check your recyclerview implementation is correct!!

Comment: First, try simply displaying textviews and then load gifs.

Comment: Thanks man..your first answer really is the solution; except that since we are looking into a subfolder within the assets folder, then the gifs should be added as follows   gifs.add("file:///android_asset/gifs/a.gif");   I implemented that and its working like a charm..Thanks a lot!